# Prerequisite for a dll to be in GAC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

What is/are the prerequisites for a DLL which needs to be fulfilled to keep that DLL in GAC ? can any kind of DLL can be kept in GAC?

This might be a strange question but this is what i faced in one of my interviews :)

Comment: It needs to be signed with a strong named key. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks Ben. I got it.

Comment: Not actually a duplicate of the marked question IMHO.